# Using a function result as a function argument in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA,

can you use a function result as an argument for another function? If not, what would be the best way to do it?
The following code shoud illustrate the problem: I generate data with function f_1 and want to pass the data to function f_2.

```
Function f_1(Arg_11, Arg_12)
    For i = 1 To 100
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Arg_11 * Arg_12
    Next i
End Function

Function f_2(Arg_21, Arg_22)
    For j = 1 To 100
        Cells(j, 1).Value Arg_21 + Arg_22
    Next j
End Function

Sub test()
k = 20
m = 10

g = 1

Debug.Print (f_1(k, m))
Debug.Print (f_2(g, f_1))

End Sub
```

Comment: Your functions aren't returning anything, so no.

Comment: Since you are new to VBA, you might benefit by reading up on [writing Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/writing-a-function-procedure).

Comment: Your question needs clarification. It isn't clear what you are actually trying to do with that code. What is `f_2(g, f_1))` supposed to mean? Whatever it is that you are trying to do, it wouldn't be achieved by passing one function to another, though it might be achieved by passing the *return value* of one function to another.

Comment: Let's assume f_1 returns an array of integers, how would you pass this array on to function f_2?

Comment: There is zero problem passing an array to a function which expects an array (or a variant) as one of its parameters. Not much difference between passing an array and passing an integer.

Comment: "Let's assume f_1 returns an array of integers" - since it currently doesn't, that seems to be your *actual* problem.

Comment: And how would you create this array of f_1 in the first place? As far as I know there is nothing like the Python List append() Method in VBA?

Could you give me a brief example, please?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the array `f_1` would return?

Comment: @norie the loop would fill an array with integers from 1 to 100.

`number = Array(1,2,3...,100)`

Comment: You could do that without looping - `number=Application.Transpose(Evaluate("ROW(1:100)"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but only the return value of the function is passed as an argument to another method, not the function itself.

See the example below:

```
Function NumberOne() As Integer
    NumberOne = 1
End Function

Function NumberTwo() As Integer
    NumberTwo = 2
End Function

Function Total(ByVal one As Integer, ByVal two As Integer) As Integer
    Total = one + two
End Function

Sub T()
    Dim t As Integer
        t = Total(NumberOne(), NumberTwo())
        
    Debug.Print t
End Sub
```

---

The return type doesn't really matter, unless the function returns an object where you need to set its reference using the `Set` keyword.

Therefore, the below is also valid:

```
Sub T()
    PrintThem ArrayValues()
End Sub

Sub PrintThem(ByVal values As Variant)

    Dim v As Variant
    
    For Each v In values
        Debug.Print v
    Next v
    
End Sub

Function ArrayValues() As Variant
    ArrayValues = Array(1, 2, 3)
End Function
```

Comment: Let's assume `Function NumberOne()` does not create a single number, but an array of numbers.

1. How would you create such an array dynamically as a function result and pass it to the other function in order to add the constant `NumberTwo`?

Comment: Change the return type to `Variant` and return a static array for testing, e.g. `NumberOne = Array(1, 2, 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the next adapted functions, please:

```
Function f_1(Arg_11 As Long, Arg_12 As Long) As Long
   Dim itNo As Long, i As Long
    For i = 1 To 100
        'cells(i, 1).Value = Arg_11 * Arg_12
        itNo = itNo + Arg_11 + 1
    Next i
    f_1 = itNo + Arg_12
End Function

Function f_2(Arg_21 As Long, Arg_22 As Long) As Variant
   Dim itNo As Long, j As Long
   
   itNo = 100
    For j = 1 To itNo
        'cells(j, 1).Value Arg_21 + Arg_22
    Next j
    f_2 = Array(Arg_21 + Arg_22, Arg_21 * Arg_22)
End Function
```

And test them in the next way:

```
Sub testBothFunctions()
  Dim arr, no As Long
   arr = f_2(2, 3)
   Debug.Print arr(0), arr(1)
   no = f_1(arr(0), arr(1))
   Debug.Print no
End Sub
```

Please, try forgetting about putting the values in the cells...

It is only a way to show you how this may be handled.